# how the execution happened in packages when it is loaded inside the local memory?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

While executing packages at first time the entire package loaded into memory then 2nd time execution it will executed from local memory.

if in case any update happened in any schema object which is used in the procedure within the package then how the execution happened?

its from server or local memory?

Comment: How are you defining 'local'? All PL/SQL execution happens on the server, not in your client. If a schema change affects the package then it will be recompiled; existing sessions that are already using the package will see the new version next time they call it, unless the package has state - the state is lost on recompilation and you'd see a 'package state discarded' error. Is that what you're getting at - I'm not sure I understand quite what you're asking, or why?

Answer (score 1):

> While executing packages at first time the entire package loaded into memory ...

When it is compiled the entire package is loaded to shared memory, but when you execute a package that is already compiled it is paged into shared memory (if it is not already) in 4kb chuncks.

As the name implies, shared memory is not dedicated to a single session.

The PL/SQL can be invalidated by changes to schema objects or other PL/SQL, in which case it is recompiled. However an individual session's context in then lost (eg your own variable values are then no longer valid). I forget which error this throws, though.

Comment: ORA-04061: existing state of package body "xxx" has been invalidated

Comment: That's the fella. Cheers.